# naming convention for the first function in curried functions

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

Is there a name convention if it comes to curried function like this:

```
const someName = argA => argB => ...
const newFunction = someName(someArg)
```

is there any convention for naming the declaration of *someName*? like prefixing it with init / create etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could take a descriptive naming, like

```
const
    multiplyBy = a => b => a * b,
    multiplyWith5 = multiplyBy(5);

var array = [3, 14],
    result = array.map(multiplyWith5);
```

Comment: what about functions in which first argument is just a dependency? lets say i have an API class that i pass as first argument to the curried function, so that when it's needed to be used i don't need to pass that API over and over?

Would that even make sense?

Comment: choose something which reflects the action of the API.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a trailing underscore: `const curriedFunction_ = () => () => {}` this way it indicates something's different.